# If array contains one 1 after one 0 in order

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to test some arrays to check if they contain:
at least one 0
at least one 1
at least one 1 after one 0

But my test of `arr.includes(0,1)` returns true for an array that should be false. They should be:

```
// var arr = [1,1,0,0,1,0,1] - should return true
// var arr2 = [1,1,0,0] - should return false
```

How can I test whether an array contains at least one 1 after one 0? thanks for any help

My code:

```
if(arr.includes(0) && arr.includes(1) && ___________) {
    console.log(true);
} else {
    console.log(false);
}
```

Comment: `arr.includes(0) && arr.includes(1) && arr.lastIndexOf(1) > arr.indexOf(0)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array items to check whether that [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) `01` or not:

```js
var arr1 = [1,1,0,0,1,0,1];
var arr2 = [1,1,0,0];
function checkData(arr){
  if(arr.join('').includes('01')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
console.log(checkData(arr1)); // true
console.log(checkData(arr2)); // false
```

Comment: This approach produces incorrect results if `arr` contains multi-digit numbers (e.g. `arr = [10, 1]`)

Answer (score 4):

You need to test the *indicies* against each other.

```js
const verify = arr => {
  let oneZero = false;
  let zeroOne = false;
  arr.forEach((num, i) => {
    if (num === 0 && arr[i + 1] === 1) zeroOne = true;
    else if (num === 1 && arr[i + 1] === 0) oneZero = true;
  });
  return (oneZero && zeroOne);
};
console.log(verify([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]));
console.log(verify([0, 0, 1, 1]));
console.log(verify([1, 1, 0, 0]));
console.log(verify([1, 1, 0, 0, 1]));
```

Or, perhaps use a `for` loop and return as soon as both conditions are found:

```js
const verify = arr => {
  let oneZero = false;
  let zeroOne = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const num = arr[i];
    if (num === 0 && arr[i + 1] === 1){
      zeroOne = true;
      if (oneZero && zeroOne) return true;
    } else if (num === 1 && arr[i + 1] === 0) {
      oneZero = true;
      if (oneZero && zeroOne) return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
console.log(verify([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]));
console.log(verify([0, 0, 1, 1]));
console.log(verify([1, 1, 0, 0]));
console.log(verify([1, 1, 0, 0, 1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty simple:

```
var prev = null;
var oneAfterZero = false;
var one = false;
var zero = false;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
    if (arr[i] === 1 && prev === 0)
    {
        oneAfterZero = true;
    }

    if (arr[i] === 1)
    {
        one = true;
    }

    if (arr[i] === 0)
    {
        zero = true;
    }

    prev = arr[i];
}

if (one === true && zero === true && oneAfterZero === true)
{
    alert('yay!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple `consecutiveIncludes` function that does what you asked

```js
function consecutiveIncludes(arr,first,second){
  for (let i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i] == first && arr[i+1] == second) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
var arr1 = [1,1,0,0];
var arr2 = [1,1,0,0,1,0,1];
console.log(consecutiveIncludes(arr1,0,1)) // false
console.log(consecutiveIncludes(arr2,0,1)) // true
```

Key here is to check one index after another

Answer (score 1):

Just do `arr.join(',').includes('0,1')`;

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) expects two arguments:

```
arr.includes(searchElement[, fromIndex])
```

The second argument (`fromIndex`) is optional, its default value being `0`.

When you call `arr.includes(0, 1)` you basically tell `Array.includes()` to start searching for `0` from position `1` in the arrays.

If your array contains numbers, the easiest way to achieve the desired outcome is to use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to produce a string an search for the sequence of values in this string:

```
arr.join(',').includes('0,1')
```

Comment: This will fail if array contain `[0, 10]`  But you could wrap inside another set of commas,  eg.  `("," + [0, 10].join(",") + ",").includes(",0,1,")`